# how make a picture box visible with a button click

Tags: c#

I have 3 picture boxes that are not visible. I want to set it up so when i click the button it show the first picture box and when i click the button again it will show the second one and same for the third. i don't want to show all 3 picture boxes at once. just one at a time.

Comment: What UI framework / architecture are you using? WPF MVVM?

Comment: If you havent tried anything and/or have no code yet then this post is premature. Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will use WinForms here, because a PictureBox is part of WinForms. This is one possible answer:

In your Form.cs just write/add this:

```
int count = 0;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (count == 0)
    {
        //Make PictureBox1 visible
        pictureBox1.Visible = true;
        count++;
    }
    else if (count == 1)
    {
        //Make PictureBox visible
        pictureBox2.Visible = true;
        count++;
    }
    else if (count == 2)
    {
        //Make PictureBox3 visible
        pictureBox3.Visible = true;
        count++;
    }
    else if (count == 3)
    {
        //Hide all PictureBoxes again
        pictureBox1.Visible = false;
        pictureBox2.Visible = false;
        pictureBox3.Visible = false;
        count = 0;
    }
}
```

Hope, this helps?!

EDIT:
If you want to get following behavior:

- button clicked for first time: First picturebox appears
- button clicked for second time: First picturebox disappears, second picturebox appears
- button clicked for third time: second picturebox disappears, third picturebox appears
- button clicked for fourth time: third picturebox disappears, first picturebox appears

then use this code instead:

```
int count = 0;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (count == 0)
        {
            //Make PictureBox1 visible
            pictureBox1.Visible = true;
            pictureBox2.Visible = false;
            pictureBox3.Visible = false;
            count++;
        }
        else if (count == 1)
        {
            //Make PictureBox2 visible
            pictureBox2.Visible = true;
            pictureBox1.Visible = false;
            pictureBox3.Visible = false;
            count++;
        }
        else if (count == 2)
        {
            //Make PictureBox3 visible
            pictureBox3.Visible = true;
            pictureBox1.Visible = false;
            pictureBox2.Visible = false;
            count = 0;
        }
    }
```

Does this help?!

Answer (score 0):

There is many solutions :) maybe complicated :p

### Example #1

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            picturboxArray = Controls.OfType<PictureBox>().Reverse().ToArray();
        }
        private int count = 0;
        PictureBox[] picturboxArray;
        public int Count
        {
            get { return count; }
            set
            {
                if (value > 2)
                    count = 0;
                else
                    count = value;
            }
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PictureBoxHandle(count);
            Count++;
        }
        public void PictureBoxHandle(int index)
        {
            foreach (Control X in this.Controls)
            {
                if (X is PictureBox)
                {
                    X.Visible = false;
                }
            }
            picturboxArray[index].Visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```